# How can I match the first unordered list from a string and select the first list items?

Tags: html, regex, preg-match

I have a content string that starts with an unordered list I want to make a summary of this content on my homepage and I need to match the first unordered list and only show 5 list items in the preview, so I stated with matching the whole ul tag using this regex:

```
/<\s*ul[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*ul>/s
```

it works fine in regex tester online but I get Unknown modifier '\' and I don't know which one ? also after getting the whole unordered list how can I choose only the first 5 list items for example:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to create the same one with only the first 5 `<li>` tags, so should I use regex or some other methods in php ?

and thanks in advance.

Comment: Escape the internal `/` as `\s*\/\s`, but really you ought to be using a proper HTML parsing library for this.  It is interpreting your `/\s` as the end of the regex, where it can't interpret `\s` as a known modifier.

Comment: Alternatively, you can delimit the whole thing with a different character like `~pattern~` so you don't have to escape slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<\s*ul[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*ul>/s
```

you need to escape the `/` if you use it as the delimiter.

```
/<\s*ul[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*ul>/s
```

in PHP you can use any character as the delimiter, though:

```
#<\s*ul[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*ul>#s
```

---

You can repeat a pattern:

```
#<\s*ul[^>]*>(\s*<li>.+?</li>){5}#sm
```

will match 5 `<li>`s. You won't be able to access them seperately, though. You can either unroll that repeated-group, or run a second expression to extract the `<li>`s.